# ¿Cómo subir un proyecto de Laravel 5.5 a un hosting?

Tags: laravel, hosting

Quiero subir mi proyecto de Laravel 5.5 al hosting gratuito ooowebhot, revise otras publicaciones y tutoriales de como hacerlo, pero no me funcionaron.
alguien sabe como hacerlo correctamente por favor?

Comment: Hola @EAGC, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: ya  lo hice gracias

Comment: Exactamente a que hosting y/o servidor intentas subir el proyecto

Comment: a hosting gratuito llamado 000webhost